# How to close fabric.js aligning guidelines?

Tags: fabricjs

Init aligning guidelines use https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js

Now i want create a switch, open or close aligning guidelines, what should i do?

Tried:

- reinit it, aligningLineColor is rbga(0,0,0,.0), transparent line. fail
- cover event mouse:down、object:moving、before:render、after:render、mouse:up, in the event do nothing. fail

Comment: do you mean you want a switch to display/hide the guidelines?

Comment: @shkaper yes, i founded, add variable enabled to aligning_guidelines.js, draw line before check is enabled, thanks